# Display all levels of a variable while tabulating in Stata

Tags: stata

I am cross-tabulating two variables variable1 with 5 levels and variable2 with 2 levels. The result of the tabulation is such that level 1 and 2 of variable1 is not displayed in the tabulation since the frequency is zero as follows:

```
sysuse auto

levelsof rep78
1 2 3 4 5

tab rep78 foreign if foreign, col nofreq

    Repair |
    Record |  Car type
      1978 |   Foreign |     Total
-----------+-----------+----------
         3 |     14.29 |     14.29 
         4 |     42.86 |     42.86 
         5 |     42.86 |     42.86 
-----------+-----------+----------
     Total |    100.00 |    100.00
```

I would like to have the tabulation with all the levels displayed as follows:

```
tab rep78 foreign if foreign, col nofreq

    Repair |
    Record |  Car type
      1978 |   Foreign |     Total
-----------+-----------+----------
         1 |      0.00 |     0.00 
         2 |      0.00 |     0.00 
         3 |     14.29 |     14.29 
         4 |     42.86 |     42.86 
         5 |     42.86 |     42.86 
-----------+-----------+----------
     Total |    100.00 |    100.00
```

How can I do that?
The reason I need this is that I have created a program that tabulates a given variable and posts the results into an excel report template using the `putexcel` functionality of Stata. In some cases some levels are not displayed in the tabulation and this results in some values getting posted to the wrong row of the excel report.

Comment: Please note http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve i.e. sample data and exact tabulation command you used providing a reproducible example are expected in a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No decent example as yet from the OP, but here is some technique.

In general, it's tricky. Stata's no metaphysician and is reluctant to display anything without empirical evidence to hand that it exists. I here create a dataset with all the cross-combinations needed and also create a variable with explicit zeros to show. For many problems, also see `help fillin`.

```
. clear 

. sysuse auto 
(1978 Automobile Data)

. contract foreign rep78, zero 

. egen pc = pc(_freq), by(foreign) 

. tabdisp rep78 foreign if !foreign, c(pc) format(%2.1f)    

--------------------
Repair    |
Record    | Car type
1978      | Domestic
----------+---------
        1 |      3.8
        2 |     15.4
        3 |     51.9
        4 |     17.3
        5 |      3.8
        . |      7.7
--------------------

. tabdisp rep78 foreign if foreign, c(pc) format(%2.1f) 

-------------------
Repair    |
Record    |Car type
1978      | Foreign
----------+--------
        1 |     0.0
        2 |     0.0
        3 |    13.6
        4 |    40.9
        5 |    40.9
        . |     4.5
-------------------
```

Commands that create tables echoing what you give them (notably `tabdisp`) are here more helpful than commands that create summaries and then create tables that show the summaries (e.g. `tabulate`, `table`).

Comment: I have edited the post giving a reproducible example for the purpose of others that would like to refer to the question. This approach solves the primary problem as I had posted. With the `tab` command I could use the nice utilities `tab var1 var2, matcell(freq) matrow(name)` in order to store the results in a matrix and then I could extract values from this matrix, perform some calculations and post the result to the excel report. Does `tabdisp` have a `matcell matrow` analog?

Comment: No; looking at `help tabdisp` tells you that. It wouldn't be consistent with `tabdisp` allowing multiple variables per cell. For export to Excel, why not just export the table contents which are in the dataset?

Comment: Yes, alternative could be to export the data set contents that resulted from using `tabdisp`. The issue is that I am running my program on multiple variables so the main data has to be cleared from the memory each time I create a data set of the `tabdisp` result. Maybe there is a way to go around this. Anyway, I've found a way to solve the issue with the `tab` command not displaying zero frequencies. In my loop, I have indicated that if there is a case of zero frequency then post null value to excel and exit from the loop. Then move to next loop corresponding to the next variable level

Comment: Wrong way round: `tabdisp` is just what gives you a table; it leaves nothing extra in its wake. You could put the creation of a reduced dataset and the tabulation in a Stata program that gives you back the original dataset.

Comment: I agree with @NickCox in this case. Also look to see if `preserve` and `restore` can or should be used here to avoid reloading the data each time. Possibly `tempfile` as well.